Whatsapp Cloud API- How to get the typing Indicator status?
Is there any way, I can get to know status if user is typing?
We are using the whatsapp's cloud API for our project to connect with an agent.
We want the agent to know if user is typing, right now I don't seem to find any such status/event in whatsapp's cloud API.
Is it not there?
Or is there any alternative available.
Looked into documentation of whatsapp cloud API.

I'm afraid this feature is, as of now, not available on the WhatsApp API. Therefore, Twilio can't offer such a feature either.

Is the reverse also not available? Like if I want to send some event/status or webhook so that typing indicator shows up to user?

Correct, that's the same situation.
